# CSS BACKDROP FILTER: When it will be available on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-filters

I've been searching for CSS Backdrop Filter recently. I am an Information Technology Student and been love designing web. I got Excited on blurry effect behind an element like an iOS like, Its Dream CSS code for me. But it wasn't working on my Microsoft Edge and some browsers. I already checked it on Mac and it does work on safari. When it will be available on these Windows browsers?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. This does not belong to SO.

Comment: Backdrop filters are experimental, you shouldn't use them in production.

Comment: @Korashen: Have you never seen an HTML/CSS question on the front page? Frontend web questions have been on-topic since the very beginning, whether or not you think they're considered "programming".

Comment: @BoltClock That being said, *this* particular frontend question is a broadly speculative one where a given well-scoped answer (such as yours) only addresses like 10% of the question.

Comment: @BoltClock In case we have a misunderstanding: The particular question here is "When it will be available on these Windows browsers". So the question is, when will the browser Edge have a particular feature. This has nothing to do with coding, programming, etc. This is either blatant off topic or at least a general software question. Both are subject to be closed.

Comment: @Korashen Microsoft Edge is a web browser, which is a tool used regularly by programmers. This is very much programming-related. However, the other problems with the question still stand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature [just landed](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9160189-backdrop-filters) in Windows 10 Insider Preview build 17063 (EdgeHTML 17), so there's a good chance it will be available in the next major release of Windows 10 that's coming later this year.

Comment: Alright, I still have to wait. But is there another way of the same as Backdrop effect? Thankyou.

Comment: @Ferdie Fuentes: Besides using JS, or supplying prerendered blurred backgrounds, no.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to come with Edge 17... but that's the least of the concerns. The status [barely an Editor's Draft](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#BackdropFilterProperty), so [it's not supported by Firefox nor Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop%20filter), only Safari has implemented it so far.